# How do i get the row values instead of the row names

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have following code and it doesnt work

```
df <- data.frame (
  Bikes = c("Canyon", "Santa", "Radon"),
  Tretlage = c(1,1,3),
  Kurbel = c(2,3,4),
  Winkel = c(4,5,3)
)


plot_ly(
      type = 'scatterpolar',
      mode = "closest",
      fill = 'toself'
    ) %>%
      add_trace(
        r = df[1,],
        theta = c("Tretlage", "Kurbel","Winkel"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        name = df[1,1]
)
```

and instead of typing in r every number like

```
r = c(1,2,4)
```

i want to put in like "df" and it takes the values automatically, but somehow that doesnt happen. Does someone know why?

it should look like this:[if r = c(1,2,4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbtb6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to use a `for` loop

```
p1 <- plot_ly(
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  mode = "closest",
  fill = 'toself'
)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
     p1 <- p1  %>%
             add_trace(
           r = unlist(df[i,-1]),
           theta = c("Tretlage", "Kurbel","Winkel"),
        showlegend = TRUE,
        mode = "markers",
        name = df[i,1]
      )
  }

p1
```

-output
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how do i plot this then? i want the figure, but like this it is assigend to p1.

Comment: @AndreaBin Just type 'p1' and enter on your console

Comment: oh thanks, but it still get the same problem sadly. instead of the values 1,2,4 its assiging 0,1,2 to r.

Comment: @AndreaBin I think your indexing is wrong i.e. `r = df[i,]` also includes the first column.  You may need `r = unlist(df[i,-1])`

Comment: it should look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbtb6.jpg

Comment: What you did is almost right, but it is in the wrong direction, now its canyon but with the values of Radon. so 3,4,3 instead of 1,2,4. But we are getting closer!

Comment: @AndreaBin ok, there was another indexing issu.  The `name = df[i,1]`. Can you test it now

Comment: i think thats it! but how did you put in the other two like in the picture?

Comment: @AndreaBin I didn't get your question.  Is it uploading in stackoverflow?  I used edit -> clikc on the `image` to upload, get the image from the folder and enter

Comment: never mind i am stupid, its late haha. Yes i got everything! thanks so much!!!!!

Comment: @AndreaBin This is the full code.  May be you were using the code from my previous update.  I changed `name = df[i, i]` to `name = df[i, 1]`